# Context behind this hadith

Tags: hadith, ramadan, forgiveness

> The Prophet said, “Verily, Gabriel came to me and he said: Whoever reaches the month of Ramadan and he is not forgiven, then he will enter Hellfire and Allah will cast him far away, so say ameen. I said ameen.

I’m scared because I feel like I wasted my Ramadan. I fasted the entire month but I missed so many prayers due to laziness and some personal issues especially on the last ten days. Does this mean I won’t ever be forgiven and whatever I do now won’t count?